# how to use cycler in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

I want to cycle through the matplotlib colors, so I get the cycler, but I don't know how to cycle through the colors:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
c = mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']
```

`c` is now a `cycler.Cycler` object. But I cannot do `c.next()` or something like that. How do I call a `Cycler` to loop (cycle, really, not just loop once) through the colors?

Comment: I would suggest you read through the answers of the duplicate and see what comes close to your case. If you then still have a problem, make sure to clearly state it in the question.

Comment: You are right. That's the same question. Sorry that I didn't find that before asking. I looked, but obviously not good enough.